# How to disable swiping on click in Swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, elementor

I'm trying to disable Swiper.js functionality on a certain carousel in Elementor (Wordpress). I need it not to move slides on grab/click of a mouse.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                    const swiper_target = jQuery ( '#shiplion_swiper .swiper-container' );
                    const swiperInstance = swiper_target.data('swiper');
                    swiperInstance.slideTo(3);
                    swiperInstance.allowTouchMove(false);

                
            });
});
```

Here is what I used to control parameters of Swiper.js instance within Elementor. For example swiperInstance.slideTo(3); definitely works. While .allowTouchMove does not, giving me console error "Uncaught TypeError: swiperInstance.allowTouchMove is not a function"

Comment: Figured it out by using : allowTouchMove=false;